# same element name with different complex types

Tags: xml, xsd

This code is part of a huge series of xsd files that combines together..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Headers"
    targetNamespace="http://HttpNamespace/types"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://HttpNamespace/types"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saml ="http://HttpNamespace/saml"

>
  <xs:import namespace="http://HttpNamespace/saml" schemaLocation="Saml.xsd" />

  <xs:complexType name="ConnectionHeader">
    <xs:attribute name="key" fixed="Connection" />
    <xs:attribute name="value" >
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="keep-alive" />
          <xs:enumeration value="close" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ContentTypeHeader">
    <xs:attribute name="key" fixed="Content-Type" />
    <xs:attribute name="value" >
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="application/json" />
          <xs:enumeration value="application/soap+xml" />
          <xs:enumeration value="text/xml" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>


 <xs:complexType name="AuthorizationHeader">
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Saml" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="saml:SamlContent"/>
   </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="key" fixed="Authorization"/>
 </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="HeadersType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Header" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice>
              <xs:element name="Header" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="ConnectionHeader" />
              <xs:element name="Header" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="ContentTypeHeader" />
              <xs:element name="Header" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="AuthorizationHeader" />
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

As yo can see, in the complex type HeadersType I'm trying to create a choice between 3 complex types of the same element name "Header". All 3 types are defined in this code snippet.

But the editor keep throw me the error:

> multiple definitions of element Header causes the content model to
>   become ambiguous

So my question is how i define a multiple choice of the same element with different complex types?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The constraint "Element Declarations Consistent" says that if two sibling elements (or two alternative elements with the same parent) have the same name, then they must have the same type. This is true whether you are using XSD 1.0 or XSD 1.1.

You either have to change your content model (e.g. to use different element names), or you have to define the Header element with the union of the currently-allowed types, and use some other way to validate the constraints (e.g. XSD 1.1 assertions).